# AndEngine: list of SpriteGroup. Don't draw on the scene

Tags: android, rendering, sprite, textures, andengine

If i create a list of sprites and draw them on scene - everything is ok, but when i try to make list of spriteGroups and draw them - there is only black screen.

```
private Queue<SpriteGroup> linesToDraw;

...

//when user touch the screen we add sprites to our collection
if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
{
    linesToDraw.add(DrawHelper.getBrushLine(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd, 5f,mBitmapTextureAtlas, mFaceTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager()));
}

...

//here we try to draw sprites
while (linesToDraw.size() > 0)
    //this code is reachable
    linesToDraw.poll().onDraw(pGLState, mCamera);

...

public static SpriteGroup getBrushLine(float xStart, float yStart,float xEnd, float yEnd, float size,BitmapTextureAtlas atlas, ITextureRegion mFaceTextureRegion, VertexBufferObjectManager manager)
{
    SpriteGroup result = new SpriteGroup(atlas, 40, manager);
    for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++)
    {
        Sprite part =new Sprite((float)(xStart + i * sLength * cos), (float)(yStart + i * sLength * sin), mFaceTextureRegion, manager);
        result.attachChild(part);
    }
    return result;
}

...
```

When i use single SpriteGroup and put ArrayList into it everything is fine and i can see sprites on the scene, but List of SpriteGroup doesn't work. Maybe smth wrong with creating the SpriteGroup with the same Texture and TextureRegion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i use single spritegroup everything was fine, and in case of list of spriteGroups i need to make children visible by myself =)

in getBrushLine:
result.setChilndrenVisible(true)